# Issue with retaining loop variable value

Tags: java, android

I have an error in this piece of code where I have declared public class variable mCountryCode as String.

```
 for (mCountryCode : isoCountryCodes) {
     locale = new Locale("", mCountryCode);
     if(locale.getDisplayCountry().equals(mSpinner.getSelectedItem())) {
         mCountryCode = locale.getCountry();                        
         break;
     }
 }
```

If I use `for (String mCountryCode : isoCountryCodes)` instead then the error will go away but I am not able to sustain the `mCountryCode` string value after `break;` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, the [enhanced for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) just doesn't work like that. It *always* declares a new variable.

You can use:

```
for (String tmp : isoCountryCodes) {
    mCountryCode = tmp;
    ...
}
```

... although frankly that's a pretty odd thing to do. It seems to me that you don't really want to assign *every* value to `mCountryCode`, but only the matching one:

```
for (String candidate : isoCountryCodes) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("", candidate);
    if (locale.getDisplayCountry().equals(mSpinner.getSelectedItem())) {
        mCountryCode = candidate;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't assign to an *existing* `locale` variable, but declares a new one in each iteration. That's almost certainly a better idea... you can always assign to a field in the `if` statement if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the enhanced for loop correctly: you need to specify the type, like this:

```
for (String countryCode : isoCountryCodes) {
     ...
}
```

Now you can use your`countryCode` string in your loop as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a local variable in your `foreach`

```
for (String code : isoCountryCodes) {
     locale = new Locale("", code);
     if(locale.getDisplayCountry().equals(mSpinner.getSelectedItem())){
        mCountryCode = locale.getCountry();                        
        break;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `mCountryCode` outside of the loop, you must declare it before the loop

```
String mCountryCode = null;
for(int i = 0; i < isoCountryCodes.length(); i++){
    locale = new Locale("", isoCountryCodes[i]);

    if(locale.getDisplayCountry().equals(mSpinner.getSelectedItem())){
        mCountryCode = locale.getCountry();                        
        break;
    }
}

//mCountryCode is still assigned
```